# left join same field select all rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How to select rows in table UsrArticle which UsrId = 1?
I'm new to use join, below is my code is there something wrong it only print empty array?

table Usr

```
id    UsrId
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

table UsrArticle

```
ArticleId   UsrId
0           1
1           0
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           3
```

php

```
$UsrId = 1;

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Usr LEFT JOIN UsrArticle ON (Usr.UsrId = UsrArticle.UsrId) WHERE UsrId = :UsrId");
$sth->bindParam(':UsrId',$UsrId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->execute();

$ArticleRows = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($ArticleRows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be failing because `UsrID` is ambiguous (there are multiple possibilities for which column you are referring to). I know it's silly because your conditions are specifying that they should be the same, but that's how SQL works. Add a table alias to the prefix of that field name:

```
... WHERE Usr.UsrId = :UsrId
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. did you mean I have to coding like `"SELECT * FROM Usr LEFT JOIN UsrArticle ON (Usr.UsrId = UsrArticle.UsrId) WHERE Usr.UsrId = :UsrId"`